# Querying a remote API from a Python script

Tags: python, api

I would like to integrate the `reviews API` from Zomato in my Python script.

I know basic programming in Python, but as for API integration, I want to know

- how to proceed with the API
- what steps should be taken to query the API from Python
- how to integrate the results in my script

What are the viable options?

Comment: First [get your api credentials](https://developers.zomato.com/api), then [check out the documentation for the API](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation).  After that just send the appropriate JSON data to the appropriate endpoints(the API url + something like '/restaurant') using GET/POST requests.  Something like [the python cURL bindings](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/) would do this really well.

Answer (score 1):

You may get started with Python's `requests` module.

Quick example to get a list of categories:

```
import requests

domain = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1"
headers = {'user-key': 'your_api_key_here'}

response = requests.get("{}/categories".format(domain), headers=headers).json()

for category in response["categories"]:
    print(category)
```

This will output something like:

```
{"categories": {"id": 1, "name": "Delivery"}}
{"categories": {"id": 2, "name": "Dine-out"}}
{"categories": {"id": 3, "name": "Nightlife"}}
{"categories": {"id": 4, "name": "Catching-up"}}
{"categories": {"id": 5, "name": "Takeaway"}}
# etc...
```

Documentation for `requests` [can be found here.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably too broad to fall within the scope of this answer, but I'll do my best.

- First [get your api credentials](https://developers.zomato.com/api)
- [Check out the documentation for the API](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation).
- Use [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/) to send the appropriate JSON data to the appropriate endpoints(the API url + something like '/restaurant') using GET/POST requests.

All of these links will give you plenty of information to learn how to do exactly what you need with the Zomato API.  The best you can do is educate yourself as to how the HTTP requests work, and then follow these links to get started.